# `fullReader is null` error when loading PDF using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf.js

I'm using pdf.js to load a pdf in react.  Before the promise in `getDocument` can resolve, I get the error: `fullReader is null` (in Firefox).  In Chrome, I get a different error: `Expected a function`, which is strange because I'm passing a callback.

I've tried different ways to import pdf.js and looked at multiple examples.  I was able to get this example running successfully (https://github.com/yurydelendik/pdfjs-react) but can't get it working in my own app.

Importing pdf.js:

```
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjsLib.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
```

The `componentDidMount` function in my component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(`examplePDFUrl`);
    loadingTask.promise.then((doc) => {
      console.log(`Document loaded ${doc.numPages} page(s)`);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(`Error during loading: ${error}`);
    });
}
```

If anyone has any insight into this, I would greatly appreciate some help.  Thank you!

Comment: what is `pdfjs-dist` ... the example that works uses `pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.js`

Comment: That's the viewer layer (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/).  The example is importing from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack' (https://github.com/yurydelendik/pdfjs-react/blob/master/src/App.js#L6).  I've tried that but run into another issue.